# How to extract more than one substring from a larger substring in java?

Tags: java, jsoup

I need some help in extracting the sub strings from the table from the link  (http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/pers/hd/k/Kumar:G=_Praveen.htm)..

I need to extract ONLY the names of the authors and store it into a 2D array..
  For example:

> ```
> a[0][0]= G. Praveen kumar
> a[0][1]= Anirban Sakar.
> a[1][0]= G. Praveen Kumar,
> a[1][1]= Arjun Kumar Murmu,
> a[1][2]= Biswas Parajuli ,
> a[1][3]= Prasenjit Choudhury
> ```

and so on for the next row (till the end of the table)...
the code which i tried is given below..

I need to extract the names of the authors (substring)  and store in a 2D array ,as the names are separated by commas and : followed by the name of the article..
 I do not want the name of the article to be stored in the 2D array but only the names of person while the end of table.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
package codetrial;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.String.*;
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
import java.io.BufferedWriter.*;
import java.io.FileWriter.*;
import java.io.IOException.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            String a;
            final String url="http://www.informatik.unitrier.de/~ley/pers/hd/k/Kumar:G=_Praveen.html";              
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            for(Element element : doc.select("table div.data") ) {
                a = element.text();
                String[] names = a.split(", "); // comma and space
                String name_one = StringUtils.substringBetween(url, " ", ",");
                String name_two = StringUtils.substringBetween(url, ",", ":");
                System.out.println("person1 = " + name_one);
                System.out.println("person2 = " +name_two);
                for(String name : names) {
                    System.out.println(name);        
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider making your question easier to read and your code well formatted. Remember that we're all volunteers. Cheers.

Comment: @m0skit0: please clarify your comment as I'm not sure that I understand it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I believe the technical description for m0skit0's comment is `sarcasm`.

Comment: You might want utilize your IDE's import. Importing too many classes could cause compilation errors (if 2 classes with the same name are imported) as well as classloading more classes then necessary!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url) library to do this. See my example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class SourceCodeProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(PageParser.readAuthors("http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/pers/hd/k/Kumar:G=_Praveen.htm"));
    }
}

class PageParser {
    public static List<List<String>> readAuthors(String url) throws Exception {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements elements = document.getElementsByClass("data");
        List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        List<String> authors = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Element element : elements) {
            for (Element child : element.children()) {
                if ("title".equals(child.className())) {
                    result.add(authors);
                    authors = new ArrayList<String>();
                    break;
                }
                authors.add(child.html());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[[G. Praveen Kumar, Anirban Sarkar], [G. Praveen Kumar, Arjun Kumar Murmu, Biswas Parajuli, Prasenjit Choudhury], [G. Praveen Kumar, Anirban Sarkar, Narayan C. Debnath]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code within for loop

```
           String htmlString = element.text();
           a = htmlString.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
            String names = a.split(":")[0].split(",");
            for(String name : names) {
                System.out.println(name);        
            }
```